# Voltage divider network calculation

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

Hello I am troubleshooting a voltage divider circuit in which I know the output going to U28 pin 3 should be around 700mv. What I am measuring however is around 7.5v. How do I calculate the v out for this circuit. I know I have to account for R83 because it is a potentiometer but still I should be able to math this out and get close to 700mv but I can’t seem to calculate it right even after watching YouTube. The top photo is the actual schematic drawing but I redrew it to in the way in which I thought it works because I noticed r85 and r86 share the same ground therefore r83 and r85 must be in parallel to r114. So did I draw this out right and how do I solve for vout?[image]

Comment: R114 and R86 are also in parallel.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Remember that resistor voltage dividers can be treated as simple ratios. If Vin is R1 and R2 is ground, then the voltage between them is equal to the ratio of R1/R2. For simple stuff treat them as just plain integers.

Comment: If I assume that your "ground" node on one end of \$R_{85}\$ in the first diagram is actually connected to the node shared by pin 3, then I'd get something near \$7.5\:\text{V}\$ on pin 3. Could you double-check that wiring?

Comment: Hi jonk you are talking about pin 3 next to r83 right not u28? R83 is a thermometer adjust.  The why I drew the schematic is exactly how it is. I’m not sure if I am understanding what you are saying but do you mean that pin 3 of the thermometer is ground.

Comment: @Pilot I'm not thinking that, at all. Here's the thing. You are measuring about \$7.5\:\text{V}\$ on pin 3. I'm taking that as gospel from you. So that means I am NOT suggesting it is connected to ground, because I believe you made a correct voltage measurement at pin 3. I really do.

Comment: @Pilot What I'm suggesting is that if I accept your voltage measurement, then I have to ask myself, "What could explain this result?" Looking at your schematic, if I assume that one end of \$R_{85}\$ is *not* connected to ground as shown, but that it is instead somehow connected to pin 3 (or any of the wiring leading to that pin), then it would explain the measurement you say you got. Since it could be an explanation, it may be worth excluding by re-checking things. Use an ohmmeter and see if either end of \$R_{85}\$ appears connected to pin 3.

Comment: @jonk ok I will check to see. It sounds possible to that that could be the problem. Thanks For your help

Comment: @Pilot No problem. For now, that's all that came immediately to my mind as a "single change" to what you wrote down. I tried to find the simplest possible explanation and was surprised to find a value very close to what you measured with this suggestion. Maybe we get lucky, maybe not. I'd appreciate a note either way.

Comment: As an alternative explanation, if U28 were faulty, or simply missing a ground or negative supply connection, that could explain the results. It is connected to the node in question so you are not really measuring the voltage divider in isolation.

Comment: Testing each node voltage will tell you if you have wrong part or bad connection.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. I will Definitely check things out. This circuit it one that I am trouble shooting in biomedical tech school. They inserted a fault and I have to find it. I still wanted to know however how I would calculate for the 700mv drop across r114 going to my vout if the circuit was working. To get the 700mv do I just calculate for total current and then use the total current times r114 1M ohms to get the voltage drop.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit can be redrawn (always a good idea) like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9iBXRm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are a couple of approaches to solving the voltage value for pin 3. The one that is likely taught earlier would use a process of applying Thevenin equivalents. Let's do that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftuRar.png)</sup>

Here, \$V_\text{TH}=9\:\text{V}\frac{R_{83}+R_{85}}{R_{83}+R_{85}+R_{113}}\$ and \$R_\text{TH}=\frac{R_{113}\cdot\left(R_{83}+R_{85}\right)}{R_{83}+R_{85}+R_{113}}\$.

At this point, it's a simple voltage divider. Let's pause for a moment and look at it more closely before moving on to the next step. Here, you can see that \$R_\text{TH}\$ is followed by a \$1\:\text{M}\Omega\$ resistor. Since \$R_\text{TH}\$ can't be very large by comparison (a few thousands of Ohms, but nothing close to the value of \$R_{114}\$), we can easily see even at this point that the potentiometer can only vary the pin 3 voltage a little bit. I think that's clear at this point, already.

The above was step 1. But there is another step yet needed to get the pin voltage:

$$\begin{align*}
V_\text{pin 3} &= V_\text{TH}\frac{R_{86}}{R_\text{TH}+R_{114}+R_{86}}\tag{Step 2}\\\\
&=9\:\text{V}\cdot\frac{R_{83}+R_{85}}{R_{83}+R_{85}+R_{113}}\cdot\frac{R_{86}}{\frac{R_{113}\cdot\left(R_{83}+R_{85}\right)}{R_{83}+R_{85}+R_{113}}+R_{114}+R_{86}}\\\\
&=9\:\text{V}\cdot R_{86}\cdot\frac{R_{83}+R_{85}}{R_{113}\cdot\left(R_{83}+R_{85}\right)+\left(R_{114}+R_{86}\right)\cdot\left(R_{83}+R_{85}+R_{113}\right)}\\\\
&=9\:\text{V}\cdot \frac{R_{86}}{R_{113}+\left(R_{114}+R_{86}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_{113}}{R_{83}+R_{85}}\right)}\tag{Final}
\end{align*}$$

That last step is actually very helpful because it isolates potentiometer \$R_{83}\$ and allows you to see better what impact it has on the whole structure of the answer here.

Another approach would be to use nodal analysis and solve the simultaneous equations (two of them.) But the result would be the same and the above relies on limited knowledge of less powerful tools (if perhaps still some algebra.)

---

I would still like to hear about what you find in your process of tracking down the problem, too. Please let us know what you find.

Answer (score 0):

This mixture of resistors can be presented as two cascaded voltage dividers since the second one has high input resistance and loads slightly the first. The variable resistor should be considered in the middle position (R = 2.5 k). Then VOUT = 9.15/(10 +15) x 147/(1000 + 147) = 0.7 V.

[image]